# can't clear inverval called in function from other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I can't figure out why this variable is becoming private to the function, even if i try to clear the interval from the console it can't find the variable, I must be doing something stupid. help please, code is below: I cut it down to the relevant parts.

```
function attack() {
  $("#container").append("<div id='attacker' style='position:absolute; width: 128px; bottom:125px'>       <img src='attacker.gif' ></div>");
  $("#attacker").css("left", $( window ).width());
  attackerCheck = setInterval( function() { moveNclear("#attacker", "attackerCheck"); }, 33 );
}

function moveNclear(objectName, intervalname) {
  objectP = $(objectName).position();
  $(objectName).css("left", (objectP.left - 10) + "px");
  if(objectP.left < 0) {
    console.log("done");
    clearInterval(intervalname);
  }
}
```

Comment: How/Where are you calling `moveNclear` ?

Comment: i thought by not putting "var" before it, then it automatically becomes global? could you tell me how to make it global, i figured this is the problem.

Comment: moveNclear is being called by an interval from the attack function, which will be called from something else

Comment: You pass the string `"attackerCheck"`. Should be the interval reference `attackerCheck`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid having to pass the interval reference by making a suitable return from `moveNclear()`, and testing it back in the calling function.

Also, `$("#attacker")` (many times over) is horribly inefficient ... and avoidable.

Finally, don't forget to localise your variables with `var`. Don't use globals.

Try :

```
function attack() {
    var $attacker = $("<div id='attacker' style='position:absolute; width:128px; bottom:125px'>       <img src='attacker.gif' /></div>").appendTo("#container").css('left', $(window).width());
    var attackerCheck = setInterval(function() {
        if(moveNclear($attacker)) {
            clearInterval(attackerCheck);
            console.log("done");
        }
    }, 33);
}

function moveNclear($el) {
    var pos = $el.position();
    pos.left -= 10;
    $el.css("left", pos.left + 'px');
    return (pos.left <= 0);//true:animation complete; false:animation in progress
}
```

Comment: @dprogramz, not necessarily mistakes. There's no such thing as "totally correct" in this stuff. It's largely a matter of style.

Answer (score 0):

```
var attackerCheck = null;
function attack()
{
$("#container").append("<div id='attacker' style='position:absolute; width: 128px;    bottom:125px'>       <img src='attacker.gif' ></div>");
$("#attacker").css("left", $( window ).width());
attackerCheck = setInterval( function() { moveNclear("#attacker"); }, 33 );

}

function moveNclear(objectName)
{
objectP = $(objectName).position();
$(objectName).css("left", (objectP.left - 10) + "px");
if(objectP.left < 0)
{
console.log("done");
clearInterval(attackerCheck);
}

}
```